# binding a variable to a paragraph tag in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I do not know angular 2 very well, and i know this is a simple thing, but i cant seem to nail it.

```
export class ActivityDesignerComponent {

whatever: any;

@ViewChild('canvasTest') canvasTest: ElementRef;


constructor() {}

// Mouse Sidebar Actions
openMouseNav() {
document.getElementById("mouse_sidenav").style.width = "292px";
}

closeMouseNav() {
document.getElementById("mouse_sidenav").style.width = "0";
}

mouseClickNav() {

document.getElementById('mouseClickNav').style.width = '319px';

let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = 
this.canvasTest.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
  // var status = document.getElementById('status');
  // status.innerHTML = mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY;
});

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
  console.log('Mouse Click At:', mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY);

  this.whatever = mouseX;

});


}

}
```

It console logs just fine.

I want to output the mouseX variable to a paragraph tag in html. I believe this is achieved by [(ngModel)] but i cant figure out how. ideas?

Comment: Store it in a variable, say `this.whatever`, and then your `p` tag will be `<p>{{whatever}}</p>`

Comment: I have tried that. I set a variable right under the export class as whatever:any, then after the console.log i set mouseX = this.whatever, but it causes an error. Any ideas?

Comment: What error? It should be `this.whatever = mouseX`

Comment: I added to the code above. in my IDE, this.whatever is throwing an error.

Comment: Change the `function(event) {` to `(event) => {` which will bind the context of `this`

Comment: thanks, that worked a treat. I also needed to change whatever:any to whatever:""

Answer (score 0):

Following up on user184994's answer...

The value of `this` is not preserved inside your two event listeners.

Edit your function to use [ES6 arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and `this.whatever` will update as expected.

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
  console.log('Mouse Click At:', mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY);

  connsole.log(this); // `this` is now equal to an instance of ActivityDesignerComponent

  this.whatever = mouseX;

});
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the use of anonymous functions altogether. By moving your logic into a method of ActivityDesignerComponent, you can also preserve the meaning of `this` through the use of [the bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
updateMousePos(): void {
   const mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
   const mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
   console.log('Mouse Click At:', mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY);

   connsole.log(this); // `this` is still equal to an instance of ActivityDesignerComponent

   this.whatever = mouseX;
}

....

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', this.updateMousePos.bind(this);
```

[Working Example on StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2w5lh)

It's worth adding that this behavior is not unique to Angular or even TypeScript. This is how JavaScript works.

Comment: The bottom one looks interesting, not sure how it works though. fiddle?

Comment: @josh_winters StackBlitz Example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2w5lh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts